# Add vertical Line with Text in between, between 2 Forms

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style a Login & Registration page and want to include a vertical line with the word in the middle, as shown below.
I already tried creating a div between the 2 forms, but I'm struggling with the word in between the line.
How can this be accomplished?

What I tried:

```
<div class="verticalline">
  <form>
  </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.verticalline{
border right: 1px solid black;
}
```

But then the line is "attached" to the left form, and I can't get it loose from it with margin or border. Also I'm not sure how to do the word in between.

[image]

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith My bad, edited the question.

Comment: Those are a lot of very nice answers, to a question with -2 votings. Thanks all of you guys, I'm reporting back soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please refer the code, it will help you. http://codepen.io/nehemc/pen/yJbRxb

```
<style>
.wrapper { width:500px; display:inline-block; position:relative; }
.wrapper:before { content:''; position:absolute; background:#900; width:2px; height:100%; margin: 0 auto; left:0; right:0; }
.left { float:left; width:190px; margin-right:40px; background:#ccc; padding:20px; }
.right { float:left; width:190px; background:#666; padding:20px; }
input { display:block; width:100%; margin-bottom:10px; }
.v-line { position: absolute; right: 0; top: 36%; background: white; left: 0; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; width: 20px; height: 20px; }
</style>

<div class="wrapper">
<span class="v-line">OR</span>
<div class="left">
  <form>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  </form>
</div>
<div class="right">
  <form>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="text">
  </form>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this turned out very useful. I implemented it. However, the text doesn't seem to be placed centered. My word is longer than 2 characters, and I can't figure out how to center it. See here: https://activemoves.de/login/

Comment: .v-line { top: 194px; width: 35px; } please change the value of top and width.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this https://jsfiddle.net/7ku7qvfx/10/

```
.verticalline{
    width: calc(50% - 1px);
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
}
p{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  margin-right: -10px;
  background: white;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be a good ground work on what I'm going to build this.

Answer (score 0):

That's the best i could come up with in 3 minutes :)

```css
form{
  float:left;
  height:100px;
  padding:0 20px;
}

.vertical-line{
  float:left;
  height:100px;
  width:1px;
  border-right:1px solid red;
}

.vertical-line span{
  display:block;
  background:white;
  padding:10px;
  margin: 30px -20px;
  z-index:10;
}
```

```html
<form>  
  user <input type='text'><br>
  pass <input type='password'>
</form>

<div class="vertical-line"><span>text</span></div>

<form>  
  user <input type='text'><br>
  pass <input type='password'>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution using an `:after` pseudo-element for the vertical line and the text as an overlaying `position: absolute` block-element.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="text">Your Text</div>
</div>
```